# How to programmatically access selected document in Team Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to programmatically get the properties of the currently selected document in Team Explorer. I tried using IVsMonitorSelection as someone had suggested elsewhere but I didn't get back details on the selected item through that. I also learned about using ITrackSelection elsewhere but I'm not sure how to use that to get to the selected document.

I also tried hitting the SelectedItems property on the application object but that turns out to be null every single time. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 connected to a TFS server 2012 as well.

I'm trying to do this within a VS addin (not a package). Has anyone faced this situation before? Any pointer will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is no direct way to do this. I asked the same question on MSDN and I ended up using copy to clipboard and getting the text (URL of the copied TFS document) for further processing in my addin. For more info: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/55932679-37c1-44ad-b5a4-962594696553/how-to-access-the-selected-document-in-team-explorer